# bash: git-receive-pack: command not found

Tags: macos, bash, git

I've just changed the git remote for my server, and now when I try to use `git push web master`, (after staging and committing the changes), I get this:

```
bash: git-receive-pack: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

It comes up immediately after pressing enter, so it's had barely any time to check the server. I've already tried adding `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin` to `.bashrc` in my home directory. I use Mac OS X, 10.9.5.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I'd start by finding out if your current PATH reflects where that command really lives.  Ty[e `which git-receive-pack`.  I've had occasions where git is trying to call a command that hasn't been installed.  Try `find / -name git-receive-pack`.

Comment: `which git-receive-pack` returns `/usr/local/git/bin/git-receive-pack`. What should I be looking for with `find / -name git-receive-pack`? It returns a whole load of paths, many with `Permission Denied.` at the end - what should I be looking for?

Comment: Well, you probably don't need to do the `find` if `which` sees it.  For future reference, you might want to run find as root (`su` or `sudo`? I assume Mac has something like that.)  It may be that `git` calls bash without using your `.bashrc`.  Can you set the `PATH` more globally?

Comment: What do you mean? What would I type in `.bashrc` to set the `$PATH` more globally?

Comment: It wouldn't be in `.bashrc`.  That's your local, user-level bash configuration.  I don't know MacOS, but in other unices you might edit `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/environment` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Just install git on the remote machine:

```
sudo apt install git
```